# The "original" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, require, es6-modules

I used to have this:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
```

Then I refactored to this (or at least my attempt to here):

```
import * as exec from 'child_process';
const execPromise = util.promisify(exec);
```

Now I am getting the error `TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object` on the `exec` in `util.promisify`

Not sure how to quite get this working like it was but with this new import syntax for Typescript (specifically related to `[@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-var-requires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
const execPromise = util.promisify(exec);
```

The `* as exec` did import the whole *child_process* module into a module namespace object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import * as childProcess from 'child_process';
const execPromise = util.promisify(childProcess.exec);
```